# AspNetCore.TestHost - headers middleware raising exceptions under parallel integration testing

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-middleware

First I create an out-of-the-box template ASP.NET Core MVC web application in Visual Studio.

I then add this Middleware:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.OnStarting(state =>
    {
        var resp = ((HttpContext)state).Response;
        resp.Headers.Add("MyHeader", "header");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }, context);

    await _next.Invoke(context );
}
```

This runs fine in a browser, and the header is seen as expected in every page response. Great.

Now I create a test project, add nuget packages 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost', 'xunit', 'xunit.runners', and put in a test:

```
    [Fact]
    public void TestHomePageParallel()
    {
        using (var server = CreateServer())
        {
            Parallel.For((long) 0, 10, index =>
            {
                Get(server, "/");
            });
        }
    }


    private TestServer CreateServer()
    {
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT", "Development");
        var directory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
        var setDir = Path.GetFullPath(
            Path.Combine(directory, @"..\..\..\..\..\WebApplication4")
        );

        var builder = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseContentRoot(setDir)
            .UseStartup<Startup>();

        return new TestServer(builder);
    }


    public void Get(TestServer server, string url)
    {
        using (var client = server.CreateClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");
            var req = new HttpRequestMessage();
            req.Method = HttpMethod.Get;
            req.RequestUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative);
            var resp = client.SendAsync(req).Result;
            resp.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

This will throw Exceptions from the Resp.Headers.Add() code in the Middleware:

```
One or more errors occurred.
One or more errors occurred.
An item with the same key has already been added.
One or more errors occurred.
An item with the same key has already been added.
One or more errors occurred.
An item with the same key has already been added.
One or more errors occurred.
etc.
```

So... Why does this happen?

Note that if you change the test loop to a non-parallel loop, there are no exceptions.

Also note that if you change the middleware code so that the Response.OnStarting() is *after* the _next.Invoke() call the problem disappears i.e. no exceptions are logged. But every example I have seen of middleware code adding headers does *not* do it this way around, and I think that it is probably unsafe and/or too late to add the callback this way:

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {    
        await _next.Invoke(context );

        context.Response.OnStarting(state =>
        {
            var resp = ((HttpContext)state).Response;
            resp.Headers.Add("MyHeader", "header");
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }, context);
    }
```

If you have VS2015 and .net core tools installed, you can download the solution yourself and try it here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57858722/HeadersNoWorky.zip

```
Full stack trace:

Test Name:  Test.Integration.TestHomePageParallel
Test FullName:  Test.Integration.TestHomePageParallel
Test Source:    C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs : line 33
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:04.226

Result StackTrace:  
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForWorker64[TLocal](Int64 fromInclusive, Int64 toExclusive, ParallelOptions parallelOptions, Action`1 body, Action`2 bodyWithState, Func`4 bodyWithLocal, Func`1 localInit, Action`1 localFinally)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(Int64 fromInclusive, Int64 toExclusive, Action`1 body)
   at Test.Integration.TestHomePageParallel() in C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs:line 36
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Test.Integration.Get(TestServer server, String url) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs:line 68
   at Test.Integration.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<TestHomePageParallel>b__0(Int64 index) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs:line 38
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1.<ForWorker64>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HeaderDictionary.Add(String key, StringValues value)
   at WebApplication4.MiddlewareHeader.<>c.<Invoke>b__2_0(Object state) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\WebApplication4\MiddlewareHeader.cs:line 20
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseFeature.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<OnStarting>b__0()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseFeature.FireOnSendingHeaders()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.GenerateResponse()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.ReturnResponseMessage()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.CompleteResponse()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<SendAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<SendAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Test.Integration.Get(TestServer server, String url) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs:line 68
   at Test.Integration.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<TestHomePageParallel>b__0(Int64 index) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs:line 38
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1.<ForWorker64>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HeaderDictionary.Add(String key, StringValues value)
   at WebApplication4.MiddlewareHeader.<>c.<Invoke>b__2_0(Object state) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\WebApplication4\MiddlewareHeader.cs:line 20
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseFeature.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<OnStarting>b__0()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseFeature.FireOnSendingHeaders()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.GenerateResponse()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.ReturnResponseMessage()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.CompleteResponse()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<SendAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<SendAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Test.Integration.Get(TestServer server, String url) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs:line 68
   at Test.Integration.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<TestHomePageParallel>b__0(Int64 index) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs:line 38
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1.<ForWorker64>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HeaderDictionary.Add(String key, StringValues value)
   at WebApplication4.MiddlewareHeader.<>c.<Invoke>b__2_0(Object state) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\WebApplication4\MiddlewareHeader.cs:line 20
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseFeature.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<OnStarting>b__0()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseFeature.FireOnSendingHeaders()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.GenerateResponse()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.ReturnResponseMessage()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.CompleteResponse()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<SendAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<SendAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Test.Integration.Get(TestServer server, String url) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs:line 68
   at Test.Integration.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<TestHomePageParallel>b__0(Int64 index) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs:line 38
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1.<ForWorker64>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HeaderDictionary.Add(String key, StringValues value)
   at WebApplication4.MiddlewareHeader.<>c.<Invoke>b__2_0(Object state) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\WebApplication4\MiddlewareHeader.cs:line 20
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseFeature.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<OnStarting>b__0()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseFeature.FireOnSendingHeaders()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.GenerateResponse()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.ReturnResponseMessage()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.CompleteResponse()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<SendAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<SendAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Test.Integration.Get(TestServer server, String url) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs:line 68
   at Test.Integration.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<TestHomePageParallel>b__0(Int64 index) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs:line 38
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1.<ForWorker64>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HeaderDictionary.Add(String key, StringValues value)
   at WebApplication4.MiddlewareHeader.<>c.<Invoke>b__2_0(Object state) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\WebApplication4\MiddlewareHeader.cs:line 20
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseFeature.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<OnStarting>b__0()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseFeature.FireOnSendingHeaders()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.GenerateResponse()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.ReturnResponseMessage()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.CompleteResponse()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<SendAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<SendAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Test.Integration.Get(TestServer server, String url) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs:line 68
   at Test.Integration.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<TestHomePageParallel>b__0(Int64 index) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs:line 38
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1.<ForWorker64>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HeaderDictionary.Add(String key, StringValues value)
   at WebApplication4.MiddlewareHeader.<>c.<Invoke>b__2_0(Object state) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\WebApplication4\MiddlewareHeader.cs:line 20
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseFeature.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<OnStarting>b__0()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseFeature.FireOnSendingHeaders()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.GenerateResponse()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.ReturnResponseMessage()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.CompleteResponse()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<SendAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<SendAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Test.Integration.Get(TestServer server, String url) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs:line 68
   at Test.Integration.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<TestHomePageParallel>b__0(Int64 index) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs:line 38
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1.<ForWorker64>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HeaderDictionary.Add(String key, StringValues value)
   at WebApplication4.MiddlewareHeader.<>c.<Invoke>b__2_0(Object state) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\WebApplication4\MiddlewareHeader.cs:line 20
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseFeature.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<OnStarting>b__0()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseFeature.FireOnSendingHeaders()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.GenerateResponse()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.ReturnResponseMessage()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.CompleteResponse()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<SendAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<SendAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at Test.Integration.Get(TestServer server, String url) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs:line 68
   at Test.Integration.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<TestHomePageParallel>b__0(Int64 index) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\Test\Test.cs:line 38
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.<>c__DisplayClass18_0`1.<ForWorker64>b__1()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvokeWithArg(Task childTask)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c__DisplayClass176_0.<ExecuteSelfReplicating>b__0(Object )
   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HeaderDictionary.Add(String key, StringValues value)
   at WebApplication4.MiddlewareHeader.<>c.<Invoke>b__2_0(Object state) in C:\HeadersNoWorky\WebApplication4\MiddlewareHeader.cs:line 20
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseFeature.<>c__DisplayClass23_0.<OnStarting>b__0()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ResponseFeature.FireOnSendingHeaders()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.GenerateResponse()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.ReturnResponseMessage()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.RequestState.CompleteResponse()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<<SendAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost.ClientHandler.<SendAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
Result Message: 
One or more errors occurred.
One or more errors occurred.
An item with the same key has already been added.
One or more errors occurred.
An item with the same key has already been added.
One or more errors occurred.
An item with the same key has already been added.
One or more errors occurred.
An item with the same key has already been added.
One or more errors occurred.
An item with the same key has already been added.
One or more errors occurred.
An item with the same key has already been added.
One or more errors occurred.
An item with the same key has already been added.
One or more errors occurred.
An item with the same key has already been added.
```

**UPDATE:**
After adding some debug, I can see that Response.OnStarting() is being called more than once for the same request, so it is trying to update the response headers twice for a single request, causing the exception. Unfortunately, I can't see why Response.OnStarting() would be called twice.

Comment: Looks like some cross-thread-synchronizing is missing?

Comment: This seems like a really odd way to be testing anyway, why do you want to  test your code via an HTTP request?

Comment: To answer both comments - I've simplified it down. In the real world, there are 100+ integration tests which run independently (but are run in parallel via the test runner) and create the issue. I've put the parallel loop into a single test to simulate the problem within a single test.

Comment: You couldn't do this anyway, it really makes no sense. Look at it this way - how can you spin up 10 webservers all listening on the same port?

Comment: I see your point, but the increased level of isolation should actually make the problem less likely to occur. The port thing is a good point though, I hand't noticed that.

Comment: It seems like you're actually trying to test load, not integration. If you really want to automate load testing, spin up the server once in the test setup.

Comment: It may look like it, but I'm not trying to load test, I'm trying to simulate e.g. 100 integration tests running in parallel. I didn't write the test setup, which is part of why I am simplifying it down to see the issue.

Comment: I've updated the code so a single server is used, but it made no difference to the outcome (see above),

Comment: It's not really possible to diagnose this one with the info you've given. Can you provide the full stack traces?

Comment: Full stack trace added (note that I have also supplied a dropbox link to download the full solution as a 7zip archive).

Comment: question edited to add note about changing Response.OnStarting() and _next.Invoke() order resulting in no exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an MS bug in the TestServer in TestHost 1.0.0

i.e. changing the project.json from this:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost": "1.0.0"
```

to this:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost": "1.1.0"
```

fixes the issue.

See here for the commit: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/852